# Snc Redis bundle set password in config.yml

Tags: symfony, redis

I set a password on my local redis server, but it gives the following error:

> "NOAUTH Authentication required."

How can I configure a Redis password in config.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify it in your dsn config.

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: 'redis://%redis_session_secret%@%redis_host%:%redis_port%'
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a simple solution :)! It works perfectly.

Comment: Done! Thanks again Carlos :)!

Answer (score 0):

For me this DSN format worked:

`redis://127.0.0.1?password=yourpass`

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: 'redis://127.0.0.1?password=yourpass'
```

Found in Wiki https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters